# Query multiple collections in one pipeline- MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a database with several collections and need to reference multiple in the same query. For example, in SQL I'd just use `union SELECT`.

**My Database:**

- car_data
- bike_data
- boat_data

**MySQL Equivalent**

```sql
SELECT "Car" AS "Type"
AVG(msrp) AS "Cost"
FROM db.car_data

union SELECT "Boat",
AVG(assesment),
FROM db.boat_data

union SELECT "Bike",
AVG(stickerPrice)
FROM db.bike_data;
```

**Desired Result**

| Type | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 40,453 |
| Boat | 64,300 |
| Bike | 215 |

I know this works differently in Mongo aggregation and looked at `$unionWith`, but I don't want to combine all my unrelated data into one doc. Hopefully the example helps convey this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- you can use union with pipeline , and union only the results
- start from the first collection and do the group
- do the 2 groups in seperate pipelines and union only the results

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3IAjzjVL94H)

```js
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "avg-cost": {
        "$avg": "$cost"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "avg-cost": 1,
      "Type": "car"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "boats",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "avg-cost": {
              "$avg": "$cost"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "avg-cost": 1,
            "Type": "boat"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "bikes",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "avg-cost": {
              "$avg": "$cost"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "avg-cost": 1,
            "Type": "bike"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```